# changing array state doesn't get child component to re-render

Tags: arrays, reactjs, components, state, rendering

I've got problem with react rendering. Here's example that doesn't seem to work correct.

```
const [testArray, setTestArray] = useState([1,0]);

      const swap =  (array, x, y)=>{
            let nw = array;
            let z = nw[y]
            nw[y]=nw[x];
            nw[x]=z;
            return nw
        }

 setTestArray(testArray=>{
               return swap(testArray, 0, 1)
            })
```

code above changes the state however when I use testArray in childs component it doesn't get re-rendered.
If on the other hand I'm manually typing array to setState it re-renders. When I assign array-variable it doesn't.

Code below works: `setTestArray([0,1]);`

This code doesn't work:

```
let array = testArray;
let current = array[0];
array[0] = array[1];
array[1] = array[0]
setTestArray(array);
```

It changes the state, but doesn't cause child component using state to re-render. I need this to work dynamically so need this somehow working :D

I'll appreciate any help given.

Comment: Don't mutate state. You modify the existing state, this gives you the same reference as before and by default all the comparisons React does are based on reference.

Comment: So if I understand properly const array = [0,1] setTestArray(array) will work cause there's no reference between array and testArray ? Is that what it's about?

In which case how can I go around that to swap items inside state array and still get my childs component re-rendered? What's the proper syntax i should use? ( apologies, new with react)

Comment: If you are only swapping items in the array the easiest way to do this would be to use the spread operator to create a new array with the same elements: `let array = [...testArray];`. This would create a new reference for the testArray state. Without seeing the rest of the code I can't say for sure, but usually the reason why state doesn't trigger an update is because it has been mutated.

Comment: Thanks for the help m8. That's all working fine now! ( And I've spent like 5hours to figure it out, started passing some dammy states to trigger update haha ) Cheers!